# Why I am getting Undefined Value when I click on image ? How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-ui

I am getting this error (undefined) when I am clicking on image to get the value of image. Can you please explain the reason behind it and how to get and pass the value to onclick function in this case.

```
      <div id="fi" value="0">
        <img src="first.JPG" alt="first" id="first" value="01" onclick="checkingg(this.value)"/>
      </div>

      // inside script tag
      function checking(img_val) {
        console.log(img_val);
      }
```

Comment: An `<img>` doesn't have a `value` property, it has a `value` attribute (which, technically, should be `data-value=`)

Comment: If you do want to keep the name "value" (which you probably shouldn't), try using `this.getAttribute('value')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem in your approach, except `value` is not a valid attribute on image and hence will be `undefined`. Use custom [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) `data-*`:

```js
      function checking(img_val) {
        console.log(img_val);
      }
```

```html
  <div id="fi" value="0">
        <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/analyzing-samples-in-test-tube-backgrounds-picture-id1290116527?b=1&k=20&m=1290116527&s=170667a&w=0&h=51bfejWaiLIK8ZeeP7u7q0b1UINUwx3dbH86HZNNuPA=" alt="first" id="first" data-value="01" onclick="checking(this.dataset.value)"/>
      </div>
```